# How to login to HTTPS chrome Sign in pop up window using selenium python?

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

Chrome version = 83 and above

I could not find any element information on the pop up.

```
    element = self.driver.switch_to.owindow(self.driver.window_handles[-1])
    element.send_keys('username')
    element.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
    element.send_keys('password')
```

This code is not working.
It throws an error as below:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys'

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same issue. After opening the website I was asked by chrome "sign in" popup for my credentials. Here is the code I solved the issue using python 3.7 in windows. This code has to run at once to keep the login windows activated while entering the credentials.

```
browser.get('https://yourwebsite')
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
keyboard = Controller()
keyboard.type('user')
keyboard.press(Key.tab)
keyboard.type('password')
keyboard.press(Key.enter)
```